# Completely hiding the y-axis in echart bar chart

Tags: javascript, charts, echarts

Using echarts 3.8.5, I am trying to create a bar chart with no y-axis labels.

Here is a snippet of my `options` object:

```
const options = {
  yAxis: [
    {
      show: false,
      type: "log",
    }
  ],

  // additional config...
};
```

The result looks something like this:

[image: chart image]

There is an empty white space to the left of the chart. It appears the space for the y-axis labels is being reserved, even though I set `show` to `false`. How can I get the chart to extend all the way to the left, without having this empty space?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"y-axis: show" is actually for the y-axis line itself.  I don't think it has to do with the labels themselves.  I think echarts is trying to keep those labels in there, but they are just not showing.

Note: Just got home from work and my original answer did not work.  Are you using a grid? I just tested it and use something like this:

```
myChart.setOptions({
    grid: {
       left: '15px',
       right: '15px'
    },
.........(add more options as needed here)
}
```

Comment: Ahh yes, I fixed this by modifying the grid properties, like you suggested. By setting the grid.containLabel to false, the full width is now used. Thank you!